# Npgsql .net example to insert into hstore from c# Dictionary

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, hstore, aws-aurora-serverless

Getting this error on passing `Dictionary<string,string>` to `hstore` type column in `postgresql`

```
Error: : 'Bytes written (44) and expected byte count (46) don't match.'
```

If I try to convert it to string in format key => value, getting below error,
`'42804: column columnname is of type hstore but expression is of type text`

Is there any way to handle hstore type from .net c# Npgsql

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Npgsql 8.0.0, then you're very probably running into https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/5445 - that has already been fixed for 8.0.1, which should get released in the next few days.